# Which call back do we get when we click "CLEAR DATA" of any application?

Tags: android, methods, callback

Android : which call back do we get when we click **CLEAR DATA** of any application ?
Steps : settings > applications > my_app > clear data !

Comment: What do you mean by callback?

Comment: if you are thinking to override clear data functionality in your app then its not possible.

Comment: Patrick- i meant to say : where can i write my code which I want to be executed whenever the user is clearing data.

Comment: G.V-  oh. thnx for the info. do u know any other way around?

Comment: @GunjanKumar There is a kind of a way to override the Clear Data functionality. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7424193/211292

Answer (score 0):

> which call back do we get when we click “CLEAR DATA” of any application ?

You do not get any "call back" specifically for this event.

That being said, I have not tried "Clear Data" with the app's process running. I would hope that "Clear Data" would terminate the process, and ideally in a graceful fashion, calling `onDestroy()` on your components.

Comment: ok i will somehow try to put my code in on destroy but i m afraid that wont solve my purpose..... thnx CommonsWare

Comment: @SP: I repeat: You do not get any "call back" specifically for this event. Hence, if your app is not running, you do not get any "call back" specifically for this event. Your app would treat this the same as it treats the first run after installation, as both conditions are identical (e.g., nothing in internal storage).

Comment: yeahhhhh i do understand. i was just thinking over ur line about "calling onDestroy()" . thnx CommonsWare. u r a big help most of the times.  \m/

Comment: I just ran a test and I found that `onDestroy()` is **not** called on the running activities when "Clear Data" is used.