# How can I disable the clear data button of android application info through ionic framework?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on app through Ionic framework. I'm saving the data into mobile through SQLite but user can clear data through clear data button in application info. I have to protect my application database from user.

How can I disable the same through Ionic framework.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Have you found any better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, there is no way you can make your app a system app. I recommend you move your data somewhere else (try mongoDB on mongoLab), or warn users not to delete the data. Someone has already answered this as well: [How to disable the Clear Data button in Application info of Manage appliaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531173/how-to-disable-the-clear-data-button-in-application-info-of-manage-appliaction)