# Disable the "Disable" button in application manager

Tags: java, android

I have an application that comes baked onto about 10 unrooted device OS's. Located in /system/priv-app. We're trying to update the application and prevent the users from uninstalling a critical update or clear the data.

I've come across a way to prevent the user from clearing data ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531173/how-to-disable-the-clear-data-button-in-application-info-of-manage-appliaction)), but I'm looking for a way to disable the "Disable" button from the app menu. Anyone know how this works? Is this something in the app configuration or is it only applicable through the OS code?

Comment: You cant disable that button as that post clearly states, but still you can save data in places that will not be erased by that...

Comment: I was referring to the second answer ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7424193/5459720)), you can switch the button for your own button that leads to a blank activity..

Comment: As far as OS goes, the user (especially a rooted one), can simply bypass any bypass, and remove the binary itself, or re-route the program to an impossible location (and thus fail the update). Can you detail your problem more: Is the device yours or under any regulation that forbids users from tempering with it (and can you call them on it)? What is the model/build number on the OS?

Comment: The device isn't under regulation, though I can receive reports from the app itself. Some of these cases I can detect and solve programmatically (for example reinstall the app in case of deletion), but I want to avoid re-deployment or remote script-running.
I'm working with Kitkat and above, no idea on specific build number.
What I'm wondering (right before I start digging in OS source code) is whether these system apps that you cannot disable/force stop are defined in their manifests/code or is this something hardcoded into the builds?