# System app vs System signature application vs Privileged app

Tags: android, system, signature

In some applications , when I go to Settings > Application > any application detail , **“Disable” button is disabled**.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/src/com/android/settings/applications/InstalledAppDetails.java )

From the above link I know **if an application is Home app or System app , it wont allow to disable that application** .

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/b58b5127040b3c843fe42544a89a1085cf7e74f6/src/com/android/settings/Utils.java

If you check the isSystemPackage() API , it seems to verify if the app is signed with system signature.

Is it because it is a **system app or because it is signed with System signature**?

I can many system apps(kept in system/apps) have “Disable” button enabled.

Also , its not mentioned anywhere that apps with System signature can’t be removed.

Or , it is a case of Privileged app stored in system/priv-app.

Comment: (I think): because the app is **System signed** it can enable/disable specific features using manifest file, (disable disable button, disable clear data button, ... etc). the second issue (app location) i think only pre-installed apps can be placed on that path. **OR** the device have to be rooted so user can grant super user access level and install the app on that path

Comment: @Yazan I don't think developer can disable clear data/disable button via manifest file. Please provide some detail how it can be done via manifest. Yes, the apps for which "Disable" button is disabled are actually pre-installed. So I am wondering why some pre-installed apps can be disabled wheres as others can't be disabled.

Comment: yes they can do it but again only if the app is **System App** you can use this in your manifest (on application tag) `android:allowClearUserData="false"` it will work if your app is sys app (signed by system signature)

Comment: check this question discussing that option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531173/how-to-disable-the-clear-data-button-in-application-info-of-manage-appliaction

Comment: @Yazan , thank you for the above link. So we can handle clear data for a system app. My concern is the "Disable " button in Application Settings. Any way to disable that for system app. Also , by system app you mean app installed at system/app location or app signed with system signature, bcoz according to below link , they are quite different. https://www.ricston.com/blog/explaining-behavior-android-application-system-apps-nonsystem-apps

Comment: i think a sys app is the app signed with a System Signature. my assumption (not sure) is the Disable of Disable button is just an option, in manifest, just like clear data ?! not sure if it's exist

Answer (score 2):

After all the research , which included verifying signatures of various preloaded applications (with and without Disable button enabled ) , I have concluded it depends on the Signature.

If an app is signed with System Signature, then its not allowed to Disable that app.Also , not all preloaded apps have system signature.