# Prevent user to clear store preferences from app settings in android application.?

Tags: android, android-studio, store

I am creating an android application which i have store some data in to store preferences,Actually i want to prevent that for further work.

Now what happen user can easily delete that data from app setting.

***Is there any way to disable or hide that button from app setting?***

Comment: refer -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531173/how-to-disable-the-clear-data-button-in-application-info-of-manage-application

Comment: @Bunny its work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a SQLite database file in the external storage so it will not be deleted when the user clears cache or even delete App Data. But you can not prevent any of these to be deleted. User has full control of what can be on the device and what not.

**Edit**

As **@NileshRathod** mentioned in the comments below, you can redirect a user to an Activity to manage what could be deleted and what not simply by adding the following in your Android Manifest:

```
<!--Prevent user from deleting App Preferences-->
<application ... android:manageSpaceActivity=".MyManageSpaceActivity">
```

Comment: i knew that sqLite  is one option but i want to store data in to store preference .
do you know other options except database?

Comment: @Arbaz.in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7424193/7666442

Comment: Wow @NileshRathod Never knew that option existed. But the user will still be able to clear cache though?

Comment: @NileshRathod issue solved thanks

Comment: @Arbaz.in happy to hear that 

Comment: Just tried and I can confirm that it works. There are a bunch of useful properties in the Application Element https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element . In Android-O (8.0) the Clear Data is disabled, but can still Clear Cache which I "think" will not remove your preferences