# Setting manageSpaceActivity makes Clear Data button disabled on API 28 (Pie)

Tags: android, settings

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7424193/3084189) solution, makes `Clear Data` button disabled on android Pie (`API-28`) where it works on android Marshmallow (`API-23`) and the button changes to `Manage Space`.

Marshmallow:

[image]

Pie:

[image]

How can I have marshmallow one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add an absolute path to your class, instead:

```
<application android:label="MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
                 android:manageSpaceActivity=".ActivityOfMyChoice">
```

use:

```
<application android:label="MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
                 android:manageSpaceActivity="com.example.ActivityOfMyChoice">
```